# System.TypeException: Invalid integer: 12/06/2012

Tags: apex, datetime

```
date inn = integer.valueof(trans.stdate.trim()) + integer.valueof(payment.Net__c);
```

Getting the following error System.TypeException: Invalid integer: 12/06/2012

Here trans.stdate is of string Type.& 
My Requirement is 12/06/2012 + 4 = 12/10/2012.

How can I acheive it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for starters `Integer + Integer == Integer` so you'll never get a date with your current operation.

But if `trans.stdate` is a String representation of a date your code should look something like:

```
Date inn = Date.parse(trans.stdate) + Integer.valueof(payment.Net__c);
```

There is also the `Date.valueOf(string)` static method but that only accepts dates in the format yyyy-MM-dd so wouldn't match the format in your error message